# Not able to get the Category from calendar event

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, calendar, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

I am using a SPFx react web-part to get the events from calendar.

I am expanding the calendar events however could not able to get the `Category` column.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 public getEvents(listTitle: string): Promise<Array<any>> {
    return new Promise<Array<any>>((resolve: any, reject) => {
        let oWeb = sp.web;
        let todayDate = new Date().toISOString();
        //filter("EventDate ge '"+todayDate+"'").
        sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).select('Id,Title').renderListDataAsStream({
            OverrideViewXml: `
                <QueryOptions>
                    <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
                </ViewFields>
                </QueryOptions>   
    `,
        }).then((items: any[]) => {
            let arrItems = []
            if (items["Row"].length > 0) {
                items["Row"].forEach(element => {
                    if (new Date(element.EventDate) > new Date()) {
                        if (arrItems.length <= 4)
                            arrItems.push(element)
                    }
                });
            }
            resolve(arrItems)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error while getting event list items ", error);
            reject(error);
        });

     });
}
```

Comment: your caml query seems wrong, can you share the correct query ?

Comment: it is correct and getting the data also but  not only the Category Column

Comment: I am also facing the same issue could you please help me if you found the any solution

Answer (score 0):

Try Using your API call like:

```
// use odata operators for more efficient queries
sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.select("Id","Title","Category").get().then((items: any[]) => {
    console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: by this it will get the recurrent events

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to get you? Do you want to get the recurrent events?

Comment: Yes  I would like to fetch the all events with recurrent items